# creating new php array from two arrays by adding new keys values

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have below two arrays,

```
$category = array('available', 'notavailable' );
$values = array(1, 2 );
```

Now i want to get JSON output as below,

```
[{category: 'available', value:1}{category: 'notavailable', value:2}]
```

I tried using `array_merge` `array_combine` but could not got desired outlut with new Key values category and value,

How can i get that?

Thanks,

Comment: Take a look at `array_map()` to combine both arrays into the desired output which you then can encode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), if you have fixed keys:

```
<?php

$category = array('available', 'notavailable' );
$values = array(1, 2 );

$array = array_map(function($category, $value) {
    return ['category' => $category, 'value'=>$value];
}, $category, $values);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(json_encode($array));
echo "</pre>";
```

Output:

```
string(74) "[{"category":"available","value":1},{"category":"notavailable","value":2}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must doing like this:

```
$result = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($category); $i++) {
    $result[] = array(
       'category' => $category[$i],
       'value' => $values[$i]
    );
}

echo json_encode($result);
```